# If $A$ and $B$ are connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ then $A+B$ is also connected

Tags: general-topology

My attempt:

We know that singletons and intervals are only connected subsets of $\mathbb R$. They all are convex sets. So $A$ and $B$ are also convex sets.
Now we show that $A+B$ is convex.

Let $x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2\in A+B$, so that $x_i \in A, y_i \in B, i=1,2$.

Let $0\leq t\leq 1$.
Then
$\begin{align}
& t(x_1+y_1)+(1-t)(x_2+y_2)\\
& =tx_1+ty_1+(1-t)x_2+(1-t)y_2\\
& = (tx_1+(1-t)x_2)+(ty_1+(1-t)y_2)\\
&\in A+B\end{align}\\$

$A+B$ is convex hence it is path connected and hence connected.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum of convex sets is indeed convex (in all vector spaces over $\Bbb  R$ generally), and the proof is fine. But here we can also use that the map $s:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by $S(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous and when $A$ and $B$ are (path-)connected so is $A \times B$ and $A+B=s[A \times B]$ and we use that continuous images of (path-)connected spaces are again (path-)connected. This idea will also work for the sum of compact sets e.g.